# "attempt to delete row..." crash but I'm not knowingly deleting any row

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

So I am getting this:

`2019-07-10 13:33:49.054504-0700 akin[60767:2710637] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to delete row 2 from section 0 which only contains 1 rows before the update'`

When I search my project for `deleteRows`, nothing comes up.

**Here is the stack trace:**
[image]

**Here is my code for the stack trace**

```
@objc func handlePillTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let oldContext = movingPillRight.isActive ? "romance" : "social"
    let sideTouched: Side = sender.location(in: movingPill).x > movingPill.frame.width / 2 ? .right : .left
    updateModelContext(with: sideTouched)
    styleView(importance: questionCellDelegate?.importance())
    movePill(sideTouched)
    let newContext = movingPillRight.isActive ? "romance" : "social"
    if oldContext != newContext {
        pillDelegate?.changeContext(Context(rawValue: newContext)!)
    }
    guard let delegate = questionCellDelegate else {return}
    updateViewOfCell(from: delegate.question,
                         currentContext: currentQuestionContext,
                     delegate: pillDelegate as? UIViewController)
}
```

```
func changeContext(_ context: Context) {
    currentQuestionContext = context
    topBar.context = currentQuestionContext
    responseTV.safelyReload(
    questionsWrapper.question.responses.indexPaths, with: .fade )
}
```

```
func safelyReload(_ rows: [IndexPath], with animation: RowAnimation) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.reloadRows(at: rows, with: animation)
    }
}
```

I have no idea why I'm getting this bug.

Comment: Think of a reload as a delete/insert. Do technically you are deleting with your call to `reloadRows`. Basically, the rows you are trying to reload don't match the rows that are actually in the table view.

Comment: Thank you.  When we reload a table it calls `cellForRowAt` for every row.  That gave me the impression that every cell in the table is refreshed.  Does it delete all the rows, then re-insert them one by one with the tableView Data Source methods?

Comment: I wouldn't worry about whether the table view actually deletes and inserts or not when you call `reloadRows`. Just worry about why your table view's dataSource is reporting the wrong number of rows in the sections at the time you call `reloadRows`.

Comment: Okay.  Will investigate that.  Thank you.

Comment: To be clear, the the row count I am returning in `numberOfRows` is not equal to the passed in `indexPaths` for `reloadRows(at:`.?

Comment: That seems to be the case. The error indicates you are trying to reload the index path of section 0, row 2 but your data model claims that section 0 only has 1 row in it.

Answer (score 1):

The row count I was returning in `numberOfRows` is not equal to the passed in indexPaths count for `reloadRows(at:`